# test for param in url

Tags: java, spring-boot

how to using unittest check, if id is valid?

I send put request 
http://localhost:8080/xxx/xx/xxx/xxx/xxxx/9991 . 9991- it is {Id}

```
{
"endCustomerId": "9991",
"name": "John",
"lastName": "Smith",
"dateOfBirth": "1978-02-02",
"nationality": "GB"
}
```

I want to prevent following  situation
http://localhost:8080/xxx/xx/xxx/xxx/xxxx/9991

```
{
"endCustomerId": "**12431**",
"name": "John",
"lastName": "Smith",
"dateOfBirth": "1978-02-02",
"nationality": "PL"
}
```

Comment: Whats your question

Comment: check, if endCustomerId has id == 9991.

Comment: I am not sure what your question is, but I use https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath in unit tests to check if a value in JSON matches some other value.